# Vector push_back on duplicate strings with the help of delimiter

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying to read the `PATH` Environment variable and remove any duplicates that are present in it using `vector` functionalities such as - `sort`, `erase` and `unique`. But as I've seen vector will delimit each element default by newline. When I get the path as `C:\Program Files(x86)\...`, its breaking at `C:/` `Program`. This is my code so far:

```
char *path = getenv("PATH");
char str[10012] = "";
strcpy(str,path);
string strr(str);
vector<string> vec;
stringstream ss(strr);
string s;
while(ss >> s)
{
push_back(s);
}
sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
vec.erase(unique(vec.begin(),vec.end()),vec.end());
for(unsigned i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
{
cout<<vec[i]<<endl;
}
```

Is it the delimiter problem? I need to pus_back at every `;` and search for duplicates. Can anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a stringstream to chop it up, and the use a set to ensure there are no duplicates.

```
std::string p { std::getenv("PATH") }
std::set<string> set;
std::stringstream ss { p };
std::string s;
while(std::getline(ss, s, ':')) //this might need to be ';' for windows
{
    set.insert(s);
}
for(const auto& elem : set)
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
```

Should you need to use a vector for some reason, you'd want to sort it with `std::sort` then remove duplicates with `std::unique` then erase the slack with erase.

```
std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec));
auto it=std::unique(begin(vec), end(vec));
vec.erase(it, end(vec));
```

EDIT: link to docs

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: Here you are inserting in `set`, I think I need to `vec.assign(set.begin(),set.end())`

Comment: Or `set` will automatically remove duplicate fields?

Comment: @user2754070, yes a set is a container that doesn't contain duplicate. I've added a link to the doc.

Answer (score 1):

For this task it is better to use [`std::set<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) which will eliminate duplicates automatically. To read in `PATH`, use [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) to split it into substrings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different delimiter (':' or ';' to split the directories from the PATH, depending on the system). For instance, you can have a look at the std::getline() function to replace your current while () / push_back loop. This function allows you to specify a custom delimiter and would be a drop-in replacement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't so much that `std::vector<T>` is delimiting anything but that the formatted input operator (`operator>>()`) for strings uses whitespace as delimiters. Other already posted about using `std::getline()` and the like. There are two other approaches:

1. Change what is considered to be whitespace for the stream! The `std::string` input operator uses the stream's `std::locale` object to obtain a `std::ctype<char>` facet which can be replaced. The `std::ctype<char>` facet has functions to do character classification and it can be used to consider, e.g., the character `';'` as a space. It is a bit involved but a more solid approach than the next one.
2. I don't think path components can include newlines, i.e., a simple approach could be to replace all semicolons by newlines before reading the components:

   ```
   std::string path(std::getenv("PATH"));
   std::replace(path.begin(), path.end(), path.begin(), ';', '\n');
   std::istringstream pin(path);
   std::istream_iterator<std::string> pbegin(pin), pend;
   std::vector<std::string> vec(pbegin, pend);
   ```

   This approach may have the problem that the `PATH` may contain components which contain spaces: these would be split into individual object. You might want to replace spaces with another character (e.g., the now unused `';'`) and restore those at an appropriate to become spaces.